# Replace Arraylist<HashMap> on position

Tags: java, android

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //neue Oberflaeche starten
        Intent in = new Intent(this, SingleTaskList.class);;
        in.putExtra("taskItems", taskItems.get(position));
        in.putExtra("position",position);
        startActivityForResult(in, 200);
    }
```

If the user clicks on an Item, it will give the Map on it's `position` to the second Activity.

There, the user can write on an `EditText`. After clicking on the Save Button, it gives the Map with the Text written in the `EditText`.

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("taskItems",taskItems);
            returnIntent.putExtra("position",position);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Here, I get the results from the Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 200) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra("position",0);
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I replace the map on the position given the first time?

I hope it's clear what my problem is.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 200) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra("position",0);
            HashMap<String,String> items = (HashMap<String,String>) data.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");

            taskItems.set(position, items);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Can you tell me what adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); do?

Comment: It tells your list adapter to update the ui because the underlying data has changed.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [ArrayList.set](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)). From the documentation

> Replaces the element at the specified location in this ArrayList with
>   the specified object.

After your retrieve the position and map from the intent, you can do:

```
taskItems.set(position, item);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i will try this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
taskItems.set(position,item);
```

Please note that for `ArrayList<E>`, the method `set` has the function header:

```
public E set(int index,E element)
```

replaces the element at the specified position in the list with the specified `element`.